# Как сделать так, чтобы фиксировано с позиционированный элемент не перекрывал контент?

Tags: html, css

Есть сайдбар-навигация .navbar со свойством position: fixed и этот элемент перекрывает собой основной контент сайта. Как сделать так, чтобы он его не перекрывал? Я пробовал играться с z-index, но результатов это не принесло

Весь код jsfiddle.net/dxk3wjc1/

Сам сайт http://cc48161.tmweb.ru/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:  flex-end;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    max-width: calc(1800px - 105px);
    width: calc(100% - 105px);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="arrow up"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#main" class="dot active" data-scroll="main">
                            <span>Главная</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#features" class="dot" data-scroll="features">
                            <span>О нас</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#services" class="dot" data-scroll="services">
                            <span>Услуги</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#sequence" class="dot" data-scroll="sequence">
                            <span>Порядок работы</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#stages" class="dot" data-scroll="stages">
                            <span>Этапы работы</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#portfolio" class="dot" data-scroll="portfolio">
                            <span>Портфолио</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#news" class="dot" data-scroll="news">
                            <span>Новости</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contacts" class="dot" data-scroll="contacts">
                            <span>Контакты</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="arrow down"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Добавь элементу который перекрывается `position:relative;` и `z-index` сработает

Comment: добавляю для .content, но не срабатывает